# How to trigger google custom search after appending search keyword in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, search, google-custom-search

I am using google custom search ,it is working fine.Now appended search keyword in url while searching.
Now when copy and paste this appended url in new tab ,search is not working .How to trigger the google custom search with appended search keyword

```html
         <script>
(function () {
                                    var cx = '014729256687841406486:r_hyheflpag';
                                    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                                    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                                    gcse.async = true;
                                    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                                })();
```

```
                            function addExtraParams() {
                                var searchBoxWords = $("input.gsc-input").val().split(' '),
                                    appendToQueryStr = "";
                                for (i = 0; i < searchBoxWords.length; i++) {
                                    appendToQueryStr += "?keyword=" + searchBoxWords[i];
                                }
                                setTimeout(

                                    function () {

                                        history.pushState(window.location.pathname, null, window.location.pathname + appendToQueryStr + "&filter=documentation");

                                    }
                                    , 2000
                                );
                            };
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                setTimeout(
                                    function () {
                                        $('input.gsc-input').keyup(function (e) {
                                            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                                addExtraParams();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        $('input.gsc-search-button').click(function () {
                                            addExtraParams();
                                        });
                                    }
                                    , 1000
                                );
                            });
                        </script>
                        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Appended search keyword in url ,when copy and paste it in new tab - need to place the search keyword in searchbox and need to apply the search.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use Search Element Callbacks in this case? 
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#callbacks